# Is there a way to ship both freight (common carrier) and UPS for the same order for the qualifying items?

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping

My assumption is that the order would have to programmatically be broken up for this to happen, and items that qualify for freight are filtered into the "freight bucket" while UPS is filtered into the "UPS bucket"?

Misguided assumption or not?